# How to update SQL rows based on other rows with shared ID?

Tags: sql-server

Currently, I have a table that looks like below:

```
ID|Date    |Val         
1 |1/1/2016|1           
2 |1/1/2016|0    
3 |1/1/2016|0  
1 |2/1/2016|0  
2 |2/1/2016|1   
3 |2/1/2016|1   
1 |3/1/2016|0  
2 |3/1/2016|0   
3 |3/1/2016|0
```

I want to update it so that the value carries over for each ID, but not on earlier dates than when the value first appeared. Also, the value can only change 0 to 1, not vice versa. So the final product would look like:

```
ID|Date    |Val         
1 |1/1/2016|1           
2 |1/1/2016|0    
3 |1/1/2016|0  
1 |2/1/2016|1  
2 |2/1/2016|1   
3 |2/1/2016|1   
1 |3/1/2016|1  
2 |3/1/2016|1   
3 |3/1/2016|1
```

I've tried a few code combinations, but the conditional of carrying the value after the date where the value first appears is tripping me up. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm curious as to the value of storing anything other than the original Date you would assign "1" for any ID in your table then?  If it can never change back and will always exist going forward.  Just a column named ValidSince or something?

Comment: It's one of 1200 different values that are combined to calculate metrics, easier to have a flag there than a valid since date for each ID!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, using the aggregate `max()` as a window function with [**`over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) (inside a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to simplify the `update`):

```
;with cte as (
select *
  , MaxVal = max(convert(int,val)) over (partition by id order by date)
from t
)
update cte
  set val = maxVal
where val <> maxVal
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZPGWB94088

result:

```
+----+------------+-----+
| id |    Date    | Val |
+----+------------+-----+
|  1 | 2016-01-01 |   1 |
|  2 | 2016-01-01 |   0 |
|  3 | 2016-01-01 |   0 |
|  1 | 2016-02-01 |   1 |
|  2 | 2016-02-01 |   1 |
|  3 | 2016-02-01 |   1 |
|  1 | 2016-03-01 |   1 |
|  2 | 2016-03-01 |   1 |
|  3 | 2016-03-01 |   1 |
+----+------------+-----+
```

---

Prior to SQL Server 2012, you could use something like this:

```
update t
  set Val = 1
from t
  inner join (
    select i.Id, min(i.Date) as Date
    from t as i
    where i.Val = 1
    group by i.Id
  ) as m
    on t.Id = m.Id
   and t.Date >= m.Date
   and t.Val = 0
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RLEAO15622

Comment: You are a god.

Only improvement I would suggest is that this won't work with bit columns. You have to duplicate the bit column, set the duplicate as a float, run this code on the float, then transfer the values to the original column.

Comment: @I.m.rich You can just change `max(val)` to `max(convert(int,val))` -- updated the answer to reflect this.